# Installation of Helios' XML Editor into Helios based Eclipse fails

Tags: eclipse, installation, p2, rft

I am working with IBM Rational Function Tester 8.3, which is Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) based. I wanted to install XML support, so I enabled the Helios update site and chose *Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.2.3* to install. I was promted for license agreement and then the installation started as expected. After some time downloading things Eclipse showed me an error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=bootProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.resources,3.6.2.R36x_v20110628-1020
```

I also tried *Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.2.2* with the same result. I verified that org.eclipse.core.resources_3.6.2.R36x_v20110628-1020 is in the plugins folder of the installation and that it is loaded in the plugin registry. The needed plugin is available and active.

I have no idea why this happens. Please someone can shed some light into this issue. What could cause this problem? Thank you.